# Lwt.backtrace_* functions

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I've just noticed the following functions in Lwt.mli:

```ml
val backtrace_bind : (exn -> exn) -> 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
val backtrace_catch : (exn -> exn) -> (unit -> 'a t) -> (exn -> 'a t) -> 'a t
val backtrace_try_bind : (exn -> exn) -> (unit -> 'a t) -> ('a -> 'b t) -> (exn -> 'b t) -> 'b t
val backtrace_finalize : (exn -> exn) -> (unit -> 'a t) -> (unit -> unit t) -> 'a t
```

Unfortunately they are undocumented. What do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some digging in GitHub and documentation shows that these are used internally for propagating backtraces between threads when using `pa_lwt` and `-lwt-debug` is passed to `camlp4`. They are also used for the same purpose by default with `ppx_lwt`.

The `-lwt-debug` option is documented on this page: http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.5.0/manual/ (search the page for "backtrace support" to go to it).

The option to turn this *off* in `ppx_lwt` is documented here: https://ocsigen.org/lwt/dev/api/Ppx_lwt (search for `-no-debug`).

See this commit, which shows that these are used in the code generated by `try_lwt`, etc.: https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/commit/78eee34fb6247da38a3d4ea5b7872676181d47e2

*Edited: confirmed more things by looking through more code, and incorporated comment.*

Comment: This is absolutely correct. They are also used in `lwt.ppx` (and are enabled by default, in this case).

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that too :) updated the answer with this info.